# The predict()-function is returning unexpected output

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

## Problem

i have a linear regression model created with some dataset (i.d. `logAnalysis <- lm(log(wage) ~ female+exper+school)` ) everything works fine and looks as expected.

I now got a matrix of new data:

```
students <- matrix(c(
  0, 3, 10,
  1, 17, 12,
  1, 8, 9,
  0, 20, 10,
  0, 34, 9,
  0, 2, 13
), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

With the first column being the female/male trade the second being the work-experience and the third being school education. I now want to make a prediction about the expected wages. This is how I thought it would go:

```
predictionData <- data.frame(female=students[,1], exper=students[,2], school=students[,3])

predictedIncome <- predict(logAnlaysis, newData = predictionData)
```

but as it turns out `predictedIncome` is not an vector of 6 (i.d. 6 predictions, one for each student) but an vektor of [1:3296]. I cannot make sense of that. Maybe I missunderstood the whole function. But I wouldn't know what else it does.

Thank you for your help

Regards

Comment: I would be willing to bet that there are 3296 instances in your training data. The problem is that you have a typo. Your predict statement should say `newdata = predictionData` not `newData = predictionData` (lower case D in "newdata").

Comment: If you want to supply new data to the predict function you must use the data parameter of the lm function.

Comment: What is `logAnlaysis`, and should it be spelled `logAnalysis`? Seems like we've got 2 (at least) typos

Comment: Ok, that was really stupid. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was just a typo. `newData = predictionData` instead of `newdata = predictionData`.